Typescript Error Uncaught ReferenceError:
** why this Error show in Typescript: **

Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration
'getRequest' before initialization
 main.ts:41
main.ts:41
 main.ts:41

code :

    import { getRequest } from "./ts/index.ts";
    import {
      setupUi,
      handleLogout,
      handlePagination, handleLogin, handleRegister, handleCreatePost,
      showUserInfo 
    } from "./ts/index.ts";
    import { PostInfoCard, User } from "./ts/interface.ts";
    
    
    // variable globel
    export const url: string = "https://tarmeezacademy.com/api/v1"; // the main url
    export let postArray: { value: [] } = { value: [] }; // for the posts in getReqeust
    export let currentPage: { value: number } = { value: 1 }; // for the pagination
    export let lastPage: { value: number } = { value: 1 }; // for the pagination
    export let postInfo: { value: PostInfoCard }; // for the current click post info
    export let user: { value: User} // for user
    // let updatePost: boolean = false;
    export let idPost: { value: number };   // for the post id handle for the delete and update
    export let currentPostClick: { value: PostInfoCard }; // for the post click
    export let isFetching: { value: boolean } = { value: false }; // for the pagination
    
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => handlePagination());
    
    document.querySelector("#LoginBtn")!.addEventListener("click", () => handleLogin());
    
    document.getElementById("logout-button")!.addEventListener("click", () => handleLogout());
    
    setupUi();
    
    document.getElementById("RegisterBtn")!.addEventListener("click", () => handleRegister());
    
    document.querySelector("#create-post-button")!.addEventListener("click", () => handleCreatePost()); // for user profile
    
    document.querySelector(".create__post__container__home button")!.addEventListener("click", () => handleCreatePost(false)); // for home 
    
    document.getElementById("profile-user")!.addEventListener("click", () => showUserInfo(null));
    
    // request for the first time
    getRequest(false, currentPage.value);


-- the get request in the end line for code --
my tsconfig.json:

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}


using vite typescript
so how to slove this error and what is meaning and why happeing ??

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init

You have a circular dependency

how to slove this??

Don't import main.js from ./ts/index.ts

is there is  another way slove this?
